# The .csproj not able to copy .json files on Linux and macOS build servers after using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, travis-ci, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-2019

I have ASP.NET Core 2.2 app and I've been developing with VS2017, when I started using VS2019 the first thing that happened was the sln stopped building with error pointing to my .csproj files, for example

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   NETSDK1022  Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'plugin.json' ForkMeRibbon    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets   316

The cause is that in my csprojs I have certain .json files I need to be included at build time, so I have these lines in my .csproj file like below which worked fine with VS2017, but VS2019 complains. After I deleted these lines and everything worked in VS2019.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="plugin.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then however after I checked my code into github, the build servers of Azure Pipeline, AppVeyor and Travis CI are not happy, they complain that my "plugin.json" file is not found.  After some struggling, I was able to fix the build for AppVeyor by changing `image: Visual Studio 2017` to `image: Visual Studio 2019` in the yml file.

It seems like the build servers are configured with VS2017-ish configurations, unless you tell it to use VS2019 compatible configurations it will not copy over my json file thus causing errors. So far all Windows builds are fine, but the Linux and macOS builds on Azure Pipeline and Travis CI are not, for example here is a [failed build on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/FanrayMedia/Fanray), and message `error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/plugin.json" because it was not found.`

Has anyone else run into this issue and how did you solve it?

Comment: You might change `Include=` to `Update=` and try again.

Comment: Thank you Lex! I tried `Update=` and VS2019 was able to build but the Linux and macOS builds still failed with the same error message. My guess is that I need to have certain configurations in the .yml files to let Linux and macOS server environments know that my project is VS2019 compatible so that they should automatically copy over my .json files during build. Any ideas?

Comment: Your Travis CI config uses .NET Core SDK 2.2.402 which is much older than 3.0.100 used by your Windows CI task. You might try to update .NET Core SDK to 3.0.100 for macOS and Linux and then see if the issue remains.

Comment: I've tried making it 3.0.100 previously on Travis CI but it didn't work. My next step is to upgrade my app to Core 3 anyway, I'll see what happens by then.  Thanks!